# Getting "Source: ERROR" with React Native WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview, uiwebview, react-native-webview

I am trying to load a screen in a React Native WebView via a POST method with the following code:

```
<WebView source={{
    uri: 'https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php',
    method: 'POST',
    body: 'hpp_id='+preloadResponse.hpp_id+'&hpp_preload&ticket='+preloadResponse.ticket,
    }}
/>
```

It outputs the following error to my screen:

[image]

When I log the value passed to `body` it outputs `hpp_id=4TP6Htore3&hpp_preload&ticket=hpp1572015949qD9N3OayJYtdVQvA7`, which is what I expected.

OS: OS X 10.14.6

react-native: 0.61.2

react-native-webview: 7.4.2

Answer (score 0):

you will have to add the ? after index.php

```
https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php?
```

Best practice to create a variable for the URL as you are giving the query params not the body data for POST request.

```
const uri = `https://esqa.moneris.com/HPPDP/index.php?hpp_id=${preloadResponse.hpp_id}&hpp_preload&ticket=${preloadResponse.ticket}`;

<WebView source={{ uri }} />
```